# $injector:unpr unknown provider: $cookiesprovider ,$cookies

Tags: angularjs

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.0/$injector/unpr?cookieStoreProvider cookieStore translateCookieStorage translateLocalStorage translate

I don't know why this injector error comes.Currently i'm using angular 1.7 version and angular-cookies too.I need to update any other dependencies?
Can anyone help me out.

```
var myApp=angular
.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.utils',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.load',
    'ui.jp',
    //'smart-table',
    'ang-validator',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'dndLists'
]);

<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
```

I'm just using cookies for dependency and not using for any special function.

Comment: could you please add code where you're using and injecting the `$cookies`?

Comment: sorry i'm injecting only ngCookies.

Comment: ok, but could you post that code where it's injected?

Comment: var myApp=angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);

Comment: you are not injecting it. You only say to angular that you have dependency to that module. You still need to inject it.. Please provide the component's code

Comment: Have you included `angular-cookies.js`?

Comment: var myApp=angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']),Whether i used ngCookies wrongly?what is the correct way to use?

Comment: yes i have included angular-cookies.js 1.7.0 version @KaustubhKhare

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: Have you added all dependancies js files?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add complete code into it, with controllers as well.

Comment: You have added only two dependency files. You need to add others as well. You want to test it, then remove all dependencies except cookies. It will work.

Comment: Include those script tags in html file, not in js file

Comment: I have included in html file only @Rakesh Burbure

Comment: Did you check for similar issues in the project repository on github? Maybe the module that is throwing this error is not compatible with angularjs 1.7 (You should also make sure that ngCookies and angularjs are the same version)

Comment: I'm using same version for angular and angular-cookies and the version is 1.7.0@AlonEitan

Answer (score 1):

You should check your scripts. Current CDN have a working example of `angular-cookies`:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($cookies) {
  console.log($cookies);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: I used the same way but i didn't use $cookies,is that compulsory to use?@Aleksey Solovey